# Help with boost::regex trim

Tags: c++, boost, boost-regex

This regex will trim the string at line breaks. 
 I want it to trim both end *only* and preserve any line breaks in the middle.

```
string s("     Stack \n Overflow    ");
boost::regex expr("^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$");
std::string fmt("");
cout << boost::regex_replace(s, expr, fmt) << endl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make the regular expression match at the beginning and the
end of the input string(want to preserve spaces around the in-between `\n`),
`\A` and `\z` instead of `^` and `$` might meet the purpose.
For example:

```
boost::regex expr("\\A[ \t]+|[ \t]+\\z");
```

Comment: This does not seem to produce consistent results. Try to parse this for example:   string s("     Stack \n   Overflow\r    ")

Comment: Could you tell the result you expect from that input?
For example, it produced the result `"Stack \n Overflow\r"` in my environment.

Comment: My bad. The expression I wanted you to test is this string s("   Stack  \n    Over\rflow   "). The result I get is this Stack\n
flowOver

Comment: That produced `"Stack \n Over\rflow"` in my environment
(the spaces around `\n` were preserved, and the spaces at the
beginning and at the end were removed).
If you mean `flowOver` is strange, probably the cause is `\r`(carriage return).
Perhaps a code like `int main() { puts("Stack \n Over\rflow"); }` will
produce the same output(that is, `regex` stuff is unrelated).
If you mean totally different thing,
could you tell the result you expect from that input?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. The result you are getting is what I was expecting and that is what I get if I print the result to file as opposed to the console. Side note: I tried the same expression on std::tr::regex and the program crashed.( Windows VS 2008 express )

Comment: I see, glad the answer helped :-)